# Orbit of Luhman 16?

Tags: orbit, coordinate, binary-star, brown-dwarf

I am studying some binary stars and brown dwarfs. Some orbits are known and easy to find, like Alpha Centauri. However, when I look for the orbital characteristics of Luhman 16 (AB), I only get the right ascension and declination of the entire system. I can convert that to $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, but is there any defined orbit for Luhman 16 AB?

I've tried looking it up on Arxiv, but the results do not give any information regarding their orbit. Is there any resource that provides information about this subject?

Comment: Have you seen the [Wikipedia page on the system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhman_16#Orbit_and_masses).  There are links to papers there.  Not really sure what you mean by "rectangular coordinates".

Comment: @StephenG I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

The orbital parameters are given in Lazorenko & Sahlmann 2018, [Updated astrometry and masses of the LUH 16 brown dwarf binary](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2018/10/aa33626-18/aa33626-18.html), Table 5.